# How to change the basePath in Zend Framework 2 for a module

Tags: module, zend-framework2

**Note-** First, Read the question carefully.

I am new  in ZF2. Right now i am working on zend framework 2.3. I have three module in this project and i am working on Wamp.

1. Application -----------  // Default ZF2 Page.
2. Album      ------------// ZF2 Tutorial Example
3. Html       ------------// I have Created

I have created a custom layout for Html module (last one). But there is a issue of basePath. I am not getting the right page path in this module. so i change in Html/config/module.config.php   and add following script in module.config.php

```
 'view_manager' => array(
     'base_path' => 'zend/public/htmlmodule/',
     'template_path_stack' => array(
     'html' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

Now, i am getting the right basepath for this module. But now basepath automatically change for two other module such as album and application. Now i deleted the above code and add this code in `zend\config\autoload\local.php`

```
view_manager' => array(
    'base_path' => 'zend/public/htmlmodule/',
    'template_path_stack' => array(
    'html' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

Now this script had change path for all module.

Now, My question is, i want change a basepath for a particular module and layout(optional), not for all module and want different basepath for differ module. Actually without right basepath, you will not get the right image/css and js file.

Here I am sharing my module.config.php file for all 2 module.

```
<?php

//Album Module > module.config.php

return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),

'view_manager' => array(
   'base_path' => 'zend/public/album',
   'template_path_stack' => array(
       'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
     ),
 );
```

and HTML Module's `module.config.php` is:

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Html\Controller\Html' => 'Html\Controller\HtmlController',
         ),
     ),
     'module_layouts' => array(
     'Application' => 'layout/layout.phtml',
     'Html' => 'layout/custom.phtml',
 ),

 'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
         'html' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/html[/][:action][/:id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                 ),
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Html\Controller\Html',
                     'action'     => 'index',
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 ),

'view_manager' => array(
    'base_path' => 'zend/public/htmlmodule/',
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'html' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
         ),
     ),  
);
```

I want know, Where am i doing wrong and how i will get the right base path according module.

Thanks to all in advance for contribution in this question.

Comment: I read your post carefully but it is quite difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. It is your obligation to describe your problem clearly so the community can help you. Try to explain what went wrong, for instance: "<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?> in index.phtml returns '/htmlmodule' for 'HTML' module (correct), while for 'Album' module returns the same, however I want it to return '/album'."

Comment: Yes, You are right Dear..! I want basePath  /public/htmlmodule  for html module and basepath  public/album for album module.

Answer (score 1):

Add specific `base_path` keys to each view manager as you have done so then try using `$this->getHelper('basePath')->setBasePath()` for the viewModels you generate just to make sure.

As a caveat, I avoided this problem entirely by making the base path the "lowest point" in the tree, in your case:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'base_path' => 'zend/public/',
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'html' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

and then adding module specific path sections in module specific views. So if I wanted to access the album specific css or js files in the album folder under public then in my view I'd reference the base path and simply add "/album" before the rest of the path. Less headache for you I believe if you do it this way.